# MYSQL "create match on X date if team A and team B are free" using procedures & transactions

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I am trying to learn a bit more in MySQL, I was given this exercise to work on procedures & transactions. it reads as follows:

"Create a MySQL procedure named scheduleMatch that schedules a match in a tournament.

The procedure should use the following parameters:

- Tournament Name
- Name of Home Team
- Name of Away Team
- Date of Match

The procedure works by first scheduling (creating) a match on the given date between the home and the away teams. In order to do this the procedure must make sure both teams are free on the given date. "

And then we are to use this syntax to call it.

`CALL scheduleMatch(‘Tournament1’, ‘TeamA’, ’TeamB’, ‘2015-11-08’);`

```
delimiter $$

create procedure schedulematch(IN tournamentName_param varchar(40), IN       HomeTeamId_param varchar(40),
                          IN AwayTeamId_param varchar(40),IN matchDate_param date)
BEGIN

DECLARE success_entry BOOL DEFAULT TRUE;

SET success_entry = TRUE;

start Transaction;

IF NOT EXISTS (select * from match where MatchDate = MatchDate_Param AND     HomeTeamId = HomeTeamId_Param AND AwayTeamId = AwayTeamId_Param) THEN
insert into match values
(NULL, matchDate_Param,   fetch_teamID(HomeTeamId_param),fetch_teamID(AwayTeamId_param), 0, 0, 0 , 0);
SELECT 'match Added ' AS MESSAGE;
commit;
else 
rollback;
end if;


end$$

delimiter ;

CALL scheduleMatch(‘Tournament1’, ‘TeamA’, ’TeamB’, ‘2015-11-08’);
```

I thought what I have above would have worked, but it still runs the insert statement. Any help would be appreciated!

I am looking for a bit of education on this, not just the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, not used to this website yet!

Answer (score 0):

You can change that `IF NOT EXISTS` part using `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct and using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` like

```
insert into `match`
SELECT NULL, matchDate_Param,   fetch_teamID(HomeTeamId_param),
fetch_teamID(AwayTeamId_param), 0, 0, 0 , 0,
'match Added ' AS MESSAGE 
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from `match` 
where MatchDate = MatchDate_Param 
AND     HomeTeamId = HomeTeamId_Param 
AND AwayTeamId = AwayTeamId_Param);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried what you had suggested, but it is still allowing me to add multiples of the same row.  if HomeTeam(teamA) has a match scheduled on 2016-11-11, I can't add HomeTeam(TeamA) to another match on the same day. Same thing goes for AwayTeam

Comment: The solution asks for a procedure, but this solution practically dispenses with that requirement. So, while in the real world this is probably the right kind of thing, I think it slightly dodges the point of the question.